# Prove that there exists a unique differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Prove that $\exists$ a unique differentiable function $f: R \to R$ s.t. $f'(x) = e^{x^2} \forall x \in R$ and $f(0) = 0$

I'm having trouble showing the uniqueness part. This is what I have so far.
Write
$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} e^{t^2} dt$

Choose $a = 0$

$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^2} dt$

We are told $F(0) = 0$, so

$F(0) = 0 = \int_{0}^{0} e^{t^2} dt = 0$

So the integral exists. Now we must show it is unique. I am really not sure where to go from here. I think the $e^{x^2}$ is throwing me off because there is no anti-derivative. So I'm not sure how I would show it is unique here. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $G$ is another such function. Then $H:=G-F$ is differentiable with $H'\equiv 0$ and $H(0)=0$.
Then $H(x)=0$ for all $x$. Indeed, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $\xi $ between $0$ and $x$ such that $\frac{H(x)-H(0}{x-0}=H'(\xi)=0$.

Comment: So because the new function (H) still needed the same conditions, it means it is the same function? Because it kind of looks like you just found another function that works.

Comment: I see that you edited it. However, I'm still not sure I understand. It seems like you found a function H that satisfies the conditions. So it seems to me this shows it is not unique. Can you try explaining more? I am still confused.